# Каким образом знак "&" в логотипе сделать другим цветом? Нужно HEALTH&BEAUTY с красным "&" вместо HEALTH&AMP;BEAUTY

Tags: javascript

html:
HEALTH&BEAUTY
js:
$(function() {

```
$('.logo-litera').each(function() {
    var ths = $(this);
    ths.html(ths.html().replace('&', '<span>&</span>'));
});
```

main.sass:

```
.logo
    font-family: baron-g, sans-serif
    color: #ffffff
    font-size: 23px
    display: inline-block
    text-decoration: none
    position: absolute
    padding-left: $gutter
    left: 0
    line-height: 65px
    &:hover, &:focus
        text-decoration: none
        color: #ffffff
    span
        color: $accent
```

Comment: `HEALTH<span style="color: red;">&</span>BEAUTY`  ?!?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.logo-litera').each((i, el) => {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace('&', '<span>&</span>');
});
```